# How to return the text value of look up field rather than ID - SQL Query in Marketing Cloud

Tags: presto, salesforce-marketing-cloud, lookupfield

I am writing a query and when I select a lookup field "Acct/Customer name" the query return an ID (i.e 01111550023423) but when I go on Salesforce the actual field in the UI shows a actual name (i.e John Doe).

Do you know a way for me to be able to return John Doe rather than 01111550023423 while querying the same field.

Comment: Can you update your question with actual input and expected output?

Comment: What I have done is just query the contact object (via Account) and query field called FirstName and LastName. Thanks.